# Eager loading works until special case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, eager-loading

I have a Staff model, which has many staff_orders

```
class Staff < Ressource
  has_many :staff_orders
```

The staff_orders contain a from_date and a to_date.
During this time the staff member is occupied.

I want to create a dropdown list of staff members,
where behind each staff_member the dates are show, 
when he is occupied: 
*"Ralph Allen (Nov 1st- Nov 2nd, Nov 4th - Nov 5th)"*

In this case the eager loading works perfectly. I need to use the LEFT JOIN, 
as I want to list all Staff member, no matter weather they are occupied by staff_orders or not.

```
@staff_collection = Staff.joins("LEFT JOIN staff_orders ON
  staffs.id=staff_orders.staff_id").
  collect{ |x| [x.long_name, x.id] }
```

But now comes the tricky part. Now I only want to add the occupied information only of a certain time span (e.g. this week) behind the name of the Staff member.
For example:
*"Ralph Allen (Nov 4th - Nov 5th)"*

```
@staff_collection = Staff.joins("LEFT JOIN staff_orders ON
  ressources.id=staff_orders.staff_id").
  collect{ |x| [x.long_name_occupied(@from_date,@to_date), x.id] }
```

I do this by calling the name method with the filtering dates as parameters.
Now it doesn't perform the eager loading anymore.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use your original select statement and throw a where clause on it that only returns times where the start/stop date is <= @to_date.

---